# Struts 1.2 with spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts1

We are migrating power builder application. As of now, we have done 30 % of migration to struts 1.2. But we don't want to continue in 1.2. We are panning to move to struts 2 or spring mvc. Is there any way to use our already migrated struts 1.2 with spring mvc or struts 2.?

Comment: I would say no. Both Struts 2 and Spring MVC are very different compared to Struts 1.x...

Comment: Drop that **** ASAP ! o_O restart from scratch, it's cheaper in the end

Comment: I could say that migration to Struts2 much easier than Spring MVC, the number of concerns less, on the other hand Spring team dropped support for Struts.

Comment: Struts 1.2 will be about 15yrs old.. So it's better to use something new.

Comment: You could go with JSF2, If you're using Struts 1.2 I assume you're using EJB2 still, unless you upgraded to EJB3. I know lots of people still run on web servlet 2.3 if using old struts cause 'never got around to updating the web.xml'

Comment: @VeenarM AFAIK JSF2 has no migration path for Struts 1.x. The only framework that has it is Struts2 and Struts2 is active at the moment, the last beta version 2.5.

Comment: You don't need a migration path to move to JSF2, you can run them both together and migrate across slowly, similar to a large scale struts to spring conversion, its more a conversion than a migration, almost everything will need to be rebuilt however.